# What additional information does adding "already" in a question provide?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the additional information obtained from adding "already" in the following question?

1. Do you know if they **already** granted us access?

If I get rid of this word, what information do I lose?

Comment: The additional meaning (not information, as it's a question) is that the speaker wants to know if access has been granted at the time they are asking. It emphasises the fact that they are interested in an _early_ grant.